# Show that C is a circle and find its radius and centre.

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

> A transformation $T$ from the $z$ plane to the $w$ plane is given by$$w=\frac1{z+1},z\ne-1$$Show that $T$ maps the imaginary axis in the $z$ plane onto a circle $C$ in the $w$ plane and find its centre and radius.

This is from a June 2019 FP2 IAL edexcel paper. Not sure about my answer. Please help!

[image: Answer part 1]

[image: Answer part 2]

Comment: This is a june 2019 FP2 IAL edexcel paper.

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. $z=x+iy$ is a variable point, so $x,y$ are variable. $\left(\frac1{1-y^2},0\right)$ does not describe a fixed centre neither does $\frac1{1-y^2}$ describe a fixed radius.

---

To solve your question, equate the real and imaginary parts of the equality you obtained:$$iuy-vy=(1-u)-iv\implies uy=-v\wedge vy=u-1$$Isolate $y$ from the first equation and substitute for it in the second equation:$$uy=-v\implies uvy=-v^2\implies u(u-1)+v^2=0$$Thus you have shown that the image of the imaginary axis in the $z$ plane is a **subset** of the circle $C:|w-1/2|=1/2$ in the $w$ plane.

---

For proving that the image is **onto**, you will need to prove $\forall w\in C$, there exists a purely imaginary $z$ such that $T(z)=w$. You have already figured out the inverse transformation. For $w\ne0$:$$wz=1-w\iff z=\frac1w-1=\frac{-[u(u-1)+v^2]-iv}{u^2+v^2}$$Can you verify that $\mathfrak{Re}(z)=0$ whenever $|w-1/2|=1/2$?

---

As a final step, notice that $0\in C$. What purely imaginary $z$ satisfies $T(z)=0$?

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=it$ where $t$ is a real number  we get $$w=\frac{1}{1+it} = \frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{it}{1+t^2}$$

With $$x= \frac{1}{1+t^2}$$ and $$y=-\frac{t}{1+t^2}$$ we have $$x^2 + y^2 = x$$ which is a circle with center at $\big(\frac{1}{2}, 0\big)$ and radius of $\frac{1}{2}.$